# Is there any efficient way to extract multipart range response of http request?

Tags: debugging, http, http-headers

I am doing some http request with WinHttp.lib,

while Get data with Range header, such as

"GET someURL\r\n Range: bytes=4096-8191,0-4095",

received the respone data after response header like this(according to RFC2616):

================================

--46228a661764c4210

Content-type: text/plain

Content-range: bytes 4096-8191/14065

...Content Data of Rang#1

--46228a661764c4210

Content-type: text/plain

Content-range: bytes 0-4095/14065

...Content Data of Rang#2

## --46228a661764c4210--

Then ,is there any efficient way to extract the Content Data that i exactly expected of each range,while data's received as stream.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/)?

Comment: I am using HTTP as Transfer Protocol in a C++ project, anyway ,thx for Fiddler, a cool tool.